# SViewTree's Children dosen't work after first level

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, unreal-development-kit, unreal-umg

I created a Slate TreeView widget.
It works fine until I extend the first level of the tree.
Then it dosent allow me to select any of the children (That are in the second level of the tree), And it dosent even show me the subfolders of the next level of the tree.
Im aware that I need to tinker with the 
.OnSetExpansionRecursive and the other elements of code but even after looking at the source code of other classes I cant seem to figure it out.
Pics included to show you whats going on.

[Code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/keoQS.png)

[InGame View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkV0q.png)

[InGame View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvBLy.png)

Comment: can you add the code directly in the post please, I mean written not as an image . Thx

Comment: Of course, my bad

Comment: well no apperntly not, I need 10 reputation or something like that....